# Swift: How to access iOS text replacements from keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, character-replacement

I am building a custom keyboard, and I want to use the built in text replacements feature. The text doesn't change automatically for my keyboard, yet other third party keyboards do work with text replacements.

There is a `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` callback in UITextField, but that is unavailable for keyboard extensions since we have to use `textDocumentProxy`

Is there another way to access text replacements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[requestSupplementaryLexicon(completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller/1618195-requestsupplementarylexicon)

Thanks a lot to myself!